# Is there a way to use SelectedIndex AND SelectedValue on a selector?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ComboBox like this:

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PeopleDisplay **removed relative source**}"
              SelectedValuePath="Id"
              SelectedValue="{Binding PersonId}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Now, I want the PersonId property in the viewmodel to capture the selected person's Id, but I also want to set the initial selection to index 0.  When I try SelectedIndex = 0, the two conflict and SelectedValue wins so I end up with no default selection. For a few reasons, I can't add the default in the ViewModel property.

Is there any way to use both SelectedIndex to set the initial value and SelectedValue to capture the selection they make?

Comment: As I know have used `SelectedIndex` and then as per index retrieved the obj from List by using index~

Comment: Initializing SelectedIndex to zero would mean that the first element of PeopleDisplay would be selected, i.e. SelectedValue would inevitably hold the PersonId of the first element. You have to do the initialization in the view model.

Comment: I was afraid of that. But I think I can make it work, thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
list<person> persons=init from db...
persons.insert(0,new person(name="init value",id=-1))

if(PersonId<=0)PersonId=persons.find(-1).id;
```